# No such method exception when using method via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have been getting my hands dirty with Java reflection and have come across a bit of a hurdle. If I try to call the following method via reflection I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.demonking.CrossHandler.HandleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)` thrown.

Here is the code for the method:

```
public void HandleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
{
    try{
        System.out.println("i am here");

        //RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("CrossFile.jsp");
        // don't add your web-app name to the path
       // view.forward(req, resp); 
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("in exception");
    }
}
```

and here is the reflection code:

```
try {
    Method m=cls.getMethod("HandleRequest", HttpServletRequest.class,HttpServletResponse.class); // error on this line
    //Object obj=cls.newInstance();
    //m.invoke(obj,new Object[]{req,resp});
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(ex.getCause());
}
```

Note that other methods called via reflection works just fine.

here is how i am loading the class via classloader.Also note that the reflection code is placed in a servlet class's doGet method of a web app where as the class loaded and method being called reside in a different non-web application.Also the same class's other method are working just fine via reflection only this method which has httpservletrequest and response parameters is not working.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Demonking\\Documents\\eclipseprojects\\ADemoOne\\bin\\");
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[] { url};
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("org.demonking.CrossHandler");
            try {
                 Method m=cls.getMethod("HandleRequest", HttpServletRequest.class,HttpServletResponse.class);
                 Object obj=cls.newInstance();
                 m.invoke(obj,new Object[]{req,resp});
            } catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're invoking `getMethod` on the right class? Also: Java conventions state that method names should start with a lowercase character

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke yeah i ampretty sure that i am calling it on the right class but doest it make a difference in case of reflection api,having methodnames start with capital characters??

Comment: @JayD This works fine for me. Can you check if imports are same in both classes ?

Comment: For reflection purposes the name doesn't matter, as long as you don't make typos of course ;-)

Comment: @SukhpalSingh yeah imports are same in classes,but i am loading the CrossHandler class via url classloader, can this be an issue?

Comment: @JayD Maybe. Can you show how are you constructing `URLClassLoader`?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh updated post

Comment: Use debugger to see what methods exists in cls.getMethods() and see if method is here and if parameter types are the same - but ensure they are really the same, so they must pass test like `HttpServletRequest.class = methodFormClass.getParameterTypes()[0]` as it might be class loaded by other class loader, and then they might look this same, but it will be different class.